# Cyclic dependence of modules implementations on each other's interfaces?

Tags: c++, module

Is it allowed to import module A interface inside an implementation unit of module B, while importing module B interface inside an implementation unit of module A?

Comment: What issues did you encounter when you tried?

Comment: @molbdnilo I never faced any issue, I am learning about modules, and was wondering if that behavior in the question is doable, because I am used to doing that with #includes, and want to know if it is possible with modules, because as far as I know cyclic dependence of module's interfaces is not allowed, so what about the implementation units to cyclically depend on interfaces?

Comment: Look up dependency inversion. Basically it means you add a third module C that  only defines the interfaces so that A and B both can use them. (Or define 4 modules, InterfaceA, InterfaceB, A, B and solve their dependencies)